# Screenshot Save Destination

Tags: folders, screen-capture

I am constantly using the <kbd>command</kbd>-<kbd>shift</kbd>-<kbd>4</kbd> command to take a screenshot, since it is so easy, but it will always save to my Desktop, and I like having my Desktop clean. It is becoming a hassle to constantly move all my screenshots into a separate folder. Is there a way to change the save destination of the screenshots automatically? I would really like it to be able to save in a folder.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, you can change the default screenshot location with the following Terminal command where `<path>` is the location you want them to be saved:

```
defaults write com.apple.screencapture location <path>
```

Then relaunch SystemUIServer for it to take effect:

```
killall SystemUIServer
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also download a free app called "TinkerTool" if you are interested in doing it without going into the Terminal.

[image]